# Converting Text File to XML Message

Tags: java, xml

I have a requirement to convert text file to XML. The text file is of below format:

```
Records=2
Rec1=12345.xyz //Value is of Fixed length (9)
Rec2=98765.xyz //Value is of Fixed Length (9)
[Separator]
Rec1=ABCD-456 //Value is of Fixed Length (8)
Rec2=LMNO-102 //Value is of Fixed Length (8)
```

The above file needs be converted to below XML:

```
<Message_Name>
     <Node>
          <Field1>12345.xyz</Field1>
          <Field2>ABCD-456</Field2>
     </Node>
     <Node>
          <Field1>9876.xyz</Field1>
          <Field2>LMNO-102</Field2>
     </Node>
</Message_Name>
```

Please note that there can be any number of records (10/ 50/ 100.....etc).

Any solution to above requirement?

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SO is not your personal coding force (though that does sound cool). Please show us what you have attempted to do which doesn't work.

Comment: Read the text file and convert it to Java objects and then create a xml using [Java Architecture for XML bindings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Comment: Hello, To be honest I have not tried anything. This is the first time I am working on JAVA programming.

Comment: Also I would be happy if I get a valid reference. I am surely not looking for a ready-made code.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/86/t1730403-text-to-xml-java/

Another approach can be read text file as property object in java, Then use JAXB marshaller.